# Git merge branch from GitLab to GitHub

Tags: git, github, merge, gitlab, branch

I am trying to figure out how to merge a branch from a GitLab repo to a branch on GitHub.

I have come across `git merge branch`. This merges the branches to an extent by adding the commits from the branch ahead to the desired branch. What I want is that if my GitLab repo is 40 commits ahead of the branch on GitHub and I decide to merge GitLab to GitHub I get the following when merging:

`Merge branch 'develop' of https://gitlab.example.com into develop`

When clicking on this commit, I am faced with all code changes in the 40 commits.

I am familiar with `git squash` command. I have also tried it but unfortunately the desired commit was not created as I wanted.

I have seen many questions on StackOverflow discussing merging but none so far that seems to cover my question/issue.

Maybe anyone could help me?

Comment: *When clicking on this commit, I am faced with all code changes in the 40 commits.*: what else do you expect. You asked to merge 40 commits fro one branch to another, so the 40 commits are merges. What's the problem?

Comment: @JB Nizet I am simply expecting one commit covering the 40 commits with a commit title: Merge branch 'x' of ... into 'x'

Comment: What do you mean by "covering"? Do you expect the 40 commits to be transformed into a single commit? That's not what merging does.

Comment: @JBNizet That is what I expect yes. But since you say that is not what merging does. Is my expectation at all possible?

Comment: You would need to rebase and squash all the commits together before merging the unique, squashed commit. But why would you want that? That would make you lose the history, and you wouldn't know that all the commits of the gitlab branch have been merged into the github branch anymore, since you would have a different history in both.

Comment: @JBNizet when you put it this way, it does indeed sound like something I wouldn't want to do. I will stick to the way I have been doing it since (as proven) it is the best way and always works without any problems. Thank you for your reply